# Cast to Number failed for value "NaN" (type number) at path "markupPercentage"

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm try an excel to update products and I get an error due to `NaN`. Here's the error I'm getting:

```
CastError: Cast to Number failed for value "NaN" (type number) at path "markupPercentage"      
  messageFormat: undefined,
  stringValue: '"NaN"',
  kind: 'Number',
  value: NaN,
  path: 'markupPercentage',
  reason: AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: The expression evaluated to a falsy value:

assert.ok(!isNaN(val))
```

> Function

```
export function roundNumber(value: any, numberOfDecimals: number = 2): number {
  if (value) {
    if (!isNaN(value)) {
      switch (numberOfDecimals) {
        case 0:
          return Math.round(value * 1) / 1
        case 1:
          return Math.round(value * 10) / 10
        case 2:
          return Math.round(value * 100) / 100
        case 3:
          return Math.round(value * 1000) / 1000
        case 4:
          return Math.round(value * 10000) / 10000
        case 5:
          return Math.round(value * 100000) / 100000
        case 6:
          return Math.round(value * 1000000) / 1000000
        default:
          return Math.round(value * 100) / 100
      }
    } else {
      return parseFloat(value.toFixed(numberOfDecimals))
    }
  } else {
    if (value === 0) {
      return 0
    }
  }
}
```

> Code

```
case 'markupPercentage':
   article.markupPercentage += percentage
   article.markupPercentage = roundNumber(article.markupPercentage, decimal)
   article.markupPrice = roundNumber((article.costPrice * article.markupPercentage) / 100)
   article.salePrice = article.costPrice + article.markupPrice
break
```

> Model

```
markupPercentage: {type: Number, default: 0},
```

Comment: Why are you not using toFixed() for everything?

Answer (score 0):

You'll get to this `else block`, when you have `NaN` for `value` according to your if-statement:

```
} else {
  return parseFloat(value.toFixed(numberOfDecimals))
}
```

which `parseFloat` doesn't like/know how to parse `NaN` value

Comment: and how can I solve it because I'm not realizing why I get an error

Comment: Your if-statement logic is not correct ... you shouldn't do any math-calculation on `NaN` (Not A Number) value ...

Comment: but I enter it in the if (!isNaN(value)) this block is going to be executed if the value is not NaN

Comment: if value is not a number you go to the else. You then treat it as a number.

Comment: MDN is your way to go to understand what `NaN` is...

Comment: can u show me your solution with the code?

Comment: @Luca Are you sure `percentage` here has a valid `number`  ->> `article.markupPercentage += percentage`

`console.log` the value of `article.markupPercentage`, and `percentage` in your caseblock, and add to your question, if you want me to help...